# How to get the variable from url using $_GET and set it as the default value of the dropdown

Tags: php

In the select dropdown, I'm trying to get the variable from URL using $_GET[], and the drop-down selected value will be based on the value get from the URL. 
 Somehow it fails, any thoughts?

```php
<select name="ForceSelection">
  <option value="default" >Select Case</option> 
  <?php
    include('connect-db.php');

    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT(typename3),id AS id,typename3 FROM vaccinetype";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo "<option value='" . $row['id'] . "' if ($row['id'] == '$_GET['typeid']') echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> >" . $row['typename3'] . "</option>";
    }
 ?>
 </select>
```

Comment: The snippet feature is for code snippets that are runnable, such as html structure, css styling, or javascript.  Given this is php, and is not runnable, the snippet feature is not useful in this case.

Comment: I recommend putting all of your "heavy-lifting" logic like database queries at the very start of your PHP file, before any HTML is rendered, as it means you won't be mixing presentation with logic in your HTML.

Comment: @Codezzz Also, you have a typo on your 4th from last line.

Comment: may i ask where exactly

Comment: @Codezzz Look at the syntax highlighting?  You have an if in a string.  That's invalid syntax, at least in the sense it won't work how you intend.  You also end your php with a `?>` in that line, thus stopping any further php processing, not that it would work in the first place as there is an undefined constant `selected`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to read that code. I think it would be more clear and readable if you put like this:

```
 <select name="ForceSelection">
 <option value="default" >Select Case</option> 
 <?php

// get a value from typeid in URL 
$typeid = $_GET['typeid'];

include('connect-db.php');

$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT(typename3),id AS id,typename3 FROM vaccinetype";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

  $id = $row['id']; 

  $selected = '';

  if ($id == $typeid) {
  $selected ='selected=selected';
  } 

    echo "<option value='$id' $selected>";
    echo htmlentities($row['typename3']);
    echo "</option>";
}
 ?>
 </select>
```

Please note that I added htmlentities function because the string from database may have some characters that escape HTML output.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like your `if` statement is not executable code (its written inside a string). Maybe your iteration code shall be like this.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      $id = $row['id'];
      $typeId = $_GET['typeid'];
      $selected = '';
      if ($id == $typeId) {
         $selected = 'selected="selected"';
      }
      echo "<option value='".$id."' ".$selected." >". $row['typename3']."</option>";
    }
```

Comment: As a small note, that's not a ternary; php has a specific ternary operator, and that's not it.  That's just an `if` in a string.

Comment: Oh, my bad! Thank you for correction.